# Problemas al configurar salida rSyslog Linux hacia aws

Tags: linux, opensearch

Buen día, estoy tratando de enviar logs a un endpoint en NLB desde Syslog en un server Linux, estoy usando las variables locales local0,local1, etc. y apuntando a carpetas de etls que tengo en el mismo server, no encuentro bien como es la sintaxis del mismo, les doy un ejemplo con datos irreales pero la configuración de como lo tengo

```
#
# Logs para los ETLS y enviarlos a OpenSearch
#
local0.*                                -/ruta/etl/1/*.log
local1.*                                -/ruta/etl/2/*.log
local2.*                                -/ruta/etl/3/*.log

local0.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
local1.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
local2.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

Esto no me está funcionando, pero si uso la siguiente liga

```
*.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

O sea así:

```
#
# Logs para los ETLS y enviarlos a OpenSearch
#
local0.*                                -/ruta/etl/1/*.log
local1.*                                -/ruta/etl/2/*.log
local2.*                                -/ruta/etl/3/*.log

*.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

De esa forma si recopila todos los datos pero de todo el archivo de configuración de rSyslog, excepto las variable local.

¿Alguien conoce alguna manera de como enviar varibales personalizadas, o múltiples rutas personalizadas? Agradecería la ayuda

PD. Cabe aclarar que este es un archivo de configuración externo donde están todos los archivos .conf ("/etc/rsyslog.d/") que son tomados en cuenta en el archivo master de rsyslog "/etc/rsyslog.conf"